# How to send multiple images which is album to Telegram by pure python without any frameworks, robots etc

Tags: python-3.x, image, telegram

I know I must use https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmediagroup

I tried several different ways to pack 'media' parameter for it. Every time I get

> {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can't parse
> media JSON object"}

Here is my current text:

```
def sendMediaGroup(pict_full_filename__list, description, to_whom=None, silent=True):
    command = (T_url + "sendMediaGroup")

    sent_picture__dict = dict()
    files_content_to_send = list()

    for one_pict in pict_full_filename__list:
        sent_picture__dict[one_pict] = open(one_pict, 'rb')
        files_content_to_send.append({
                                    'type': 'photo',
                                    'media':  f'attach://{one_pict}',
                                    'caption': description,
                                    'parse_mode': 'HTML' })

    parameters = {"chat_id": str(to_whom),
                  # "media": files_content_to_send,  # it caused the error
                  "media": str(files_content_to_send).replace("'", '"'),  # correct way
                  #### "protect_content":
                  #### "reply_to_message_id":
                  #### "allow_sending_without_reply":
                  "disable_notification": silent}

    # print(prettyjson(parameters))
    # exit()
    # input()

    response = requests.post(command,
                             data=parameters,
                             files=sent_picture__dict)

    if not json.loads(response.text)["ok"]:
        print('FAILED')
        print(f'Recipient: {to_whom}')
        print(f'Reply: {response.text}')
        print()

    for key in sent_picture__dict:
        sent_picture__dict[key].close()
```

What am I doing wrong and what do I have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because you have one_pict both a filename and an identifier f'random-name-{}' between attach:// and files

Comment: This is the core. It must know which content is which. I `say' attach://"John.jpg" and when downloading picture content Telegram server must know which picture is "John.jpg"
Anyway it says "can't parse media JSON object" which is in parameters.

Comment: A couple of days ago I solved the same problem, I also had a 400 error.

400 error may occur because You are passing full filenames to f'attach://'.

This code works exactly:

Comment: def send_group(chat_id, text, filesIO_list, type = "photo"):
     media = list()
     files = dict()
     for u in enumerate(filesIO_list):
         if u[0] == 0: media.append({"type": type, "media": f"attach://name-{u[0]}", "caption": text})
         else: media.append({"type": type, "media": f"attach://name-{u[0]}"})
         files.update({f"name-{u[0]}": u[1]})
     return requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + telegram_token + "/sendMediaGroup",
         params={"chat_id": chat_id, "media": str(media).replace("'", '"')}, files=files)

Comment: Unfortunatelly 
one_pict = one_pict.split(os.sep)[-1]
did not make any sense :-(

Comment: Dear @kroner108 thank you so much.
Your example helped. The matter was in the type of "media". Dispite it is a list we have to send it as a string. "media": str(files_content_to_send).replace("'", '"'),  when creating parameters.